# Automated SMS in PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, sms

I Have MySQL Database in which one of the column contains User Mobile Number.

For Every 6 Months Each User will be Having is Examination Results

When i upload these results to Database then their Respective Result should be sent to Respective User Mobile Number Automatically Using PHP

Can any One suggest me what Requirements I Should get and What script make this work done

and that SMS Service should be in India

Thankyou

Comment: You need a sms gateway. On internet there are lots of these. Then you need their API to communicate with them and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take at look at these guy's API (for UK) - http://www.textlocal.com/

You will need to pay a little per message, but their API is so simple too hook up to your existing application.

Google it for others - like [Merca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/551451/merca) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12726502/1169669)!

Answer (score 0):

Look into SMS providers. I have worked with esendex before, they seem pretty straight forward:
http://www.esendex.co.uk/

There are few providers around, just google it.